# (GL) Can we draw multiple line strips on a single draw call?

Tags: opengl

Is there a trick to tell openGL to end a line strip at a vertex (and start a new one at the next vertex) without exiting the draw call ?

I am thinking to terminate each polyline with a {NAN,NAN,NAN} vertex, but could it have any unforeseen side effects ?

Comment: You can use [NV_primitive_restart](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/primitive_restart.txt).

Comment: This needs more information. What OpenGL version are you using? What kinds of draw calls are you using?

Comment: On opengl 3.3 using glDrawElements exclusively at this point for all kinds of geometry

Answer (score 0):

Try `GL_LINE_STRIP` as written [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml), but I am not sure if you can input vertex or terminate line with input `(NAN, NAN, NAN)` in `opengl`.

Comment: Thanks you,  yes, I know how to implement lineStrip ... but if I want to draw (say) three 'U' shaps on a single draw call they are all connected as if made by a single thread. I tried NAN and it works, but I don't want to commit to this hack if someone has experience of problems that might come from such practice.